# Linq nested Join from a group join if null

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

I'm sure this is VERY simple but for the life of me I cannot find a single example of this.

I am doing a Group Join on a table I then want to do a second join on that grouped join.

Table 1 Orders
Table 2 Contacts
Table 3 Phone Numbers

```
dim query = from order in Orders _
Group Join contact in Contacts On order.contactId equals contact.contactId Into grpContacts = Group From gcontact in grpContacts.DefaultIfEmpty()
Group Join phone in PhoneNumbers On phone.phoneNumberId Equals gcontact.homePhoneId Into grpPhoneNumbers = Group from gphone in grpPhoneNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

This query will error out on the last join when gcontact is null. Which makes sense... but how do I do this join anyway and just have null/nothing values if the record does not exist?

UPDATE RESOLVED *******
If anyone else runs into this you can add an expression after the ON operator to determine if the previous group join is nothing. Thanks moander!

```
dim query = from order in Orders _
Group Join contact in Contacts On order.contactId equals contact.contactId Into grpContacts = Group From gcontact in grpContacts.DefaultIfEmpty()
Group Join phone in PhoneNumbers On IF(phone is nothing, 0, phone.phoneNumberId) Equals gcontact.homePhoneId Into grpPhoneNumbers = Group from gphone in grpPhoneNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using iif to avoid accessing gcontact when it is null:

```
Equals iif(gcontact is nothing, 0, gcontact.homePhoneId)
```

Comment: Urg, please, never use `iff`. use `if` instead. `if` is an operator and should generally be preferred over `iff` (which is a function) because it provides short-circuit evaluation. If you use `iff` (which always evaluates all three of its arguments), then a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown, because `gcontact.homePhoneId` will get evaluated.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! I didnt think I could stick an expression right in the Join clause, that worked perfectly. I will update the question to show the working example.